# How to check that file is complete and not being used by other application in php

Tags: php, fopen, filesize

There's a file in my server that is being updated every 5 minutes. The file is uploaded via ftp and gets updated when upload is completed. 
I'm using a php script to get this file's data and I would like to ensure that each time my script reads this file, it's complete and valid (it's not being uploaded at the same time).

Is the following code safe and suitable for this check?

```
if ( (($handle = fopen('/var/import/data.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) && (filesize('/var/import/data.csv')>10) ) {

....do stuff....

}
```

Comment: How about locking it first: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a lockfile while the file is being updated, and delete it when the update is finished. Then check against said lockfile to know if you can read from it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat the ftp upload as two stages

1. upload (as a new file)
2. rename (to overwrite the previous version)

This *massively* reduces the chance of your script seeing an incomplete file.

Alternatively, check the modified time of the file (`mtime`) and only access the file if it's older than, say, 30 seconds. Be sure to make this time longer than the upload time.

Comment: The function is `filemtime` and it is cached, so call of `clearstatcache` is needed in this case every time we want to determine the file\`s last modified date.